# Android: create TextView at the bottom of a LinearLayout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I created an app where clicking a button I create a TextView inside a LinearLayout(hosted inside a ScrollView).
When I click the button the TextViews are displayed starting from the top like this example:

**First Image**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4SeA.jpg  (Sorry I don't have reputation to display it in the post so I inserted the link)

But my task is to create the textviews at the bottom of my LinearLayout and make the TextViews already created scroll up the new one. (Sorry for my bad english) I show an example to be more comprehensible.

**Second Image**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NcPF.jpg

**This is my code:**

```
public class Messaggi2 extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

LinearLayout mLayout;
ScrollView scroll;
Button invia; 

@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messaggi2);

    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearScrollLayout);
    scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView2);
    invia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Invia);
    invia.setOnClickListener(this);


}

 @Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("Message"));
}

private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.balloon_broadcast_incoming_pressed);
    return textView;
}
}
```

**And this is my Layout.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="640dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearScrollLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Messaggio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/balloon_broadcast_incoming_pressed"
                android:text="@string/messaggi" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_layout_bg" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Scrivi"
            android:layout_width="440dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/scriviMessaggio" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Invia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/send_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so you want to add the textView starting from the bottom going up?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Yes the textview must be created everytime at the bottom of my scrollview

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as LinearLayout.BOTTOM, nor can we add rule for LinearLayout.

But the good news is to insert into LinearLayout, one could decide the sequence.. Just use the addView function with 3 arguments as below

```
mLayout.addView(view, index, param);
```

The index determined the order.

Answer (score -2):

You need to set your linear layout's height to the height of your ScrollView so instead of using `wrap_content` cause that is wrapping your linearlayout change it to `match_parent`

**example:**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearScrollLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

When you want to add the button at the bottom of the linearlayout just add a rule to your layout params.

**example:**

```
    private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) txt1.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.addRule(LinearLayout.BOTTOM, 1);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.balloon_broadcast_incoming_pressed);
    return textView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer but I can't find the rule LinearLayout.Bottom

Comment: The answer above is wrong as found out by http://stackoverflow.com/q/37451778/3286489